# How to filter Longlistselector WP7

Tags: wpf, longlistselector

I got problem while try to filter LongListSelector with textbox in WP7. I want to

Group A:
AABBCC
AABBDD
AABBEE

Group B:
BBCCDD
BBDDEE
BBEEFF

When i type the text "BBCC" in textbox, the list will be display

Group A:
AABBCC

Group B:
BBCCDD

I have sucessed implement this filter with ListBox.

```
ItemSearch = new CollectionViewSource();
Item = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(); 
ItemSearch.Source = Item;
```

For filter i use this code

```
ItemSearch.View.Filter  = FilterList

private bool FilterList(object obj)
{
return ...... ;
}
```

But in LongListSelector, i don't know how to filter the list with model view like

```
Item = new ObservableCollection<Group<ItemViewModel>>()
```

Anyone have any suggest for me.

Thanks